# Python Version Dependency Issue - pip uninstall

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to uninstall matplotlib or upgrade pip.  For example:

```
%pip install --upgrade pip
```

After it downloads pip and installs it, it tries to uninstall the old version. I get the error:

```
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pip  
  Downloading pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB)  
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.2MB 506kB/s   
Installing collected packages: pip  
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.0  
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.0:  
Exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 726, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)  
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 314, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
    rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
  File   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())  
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt'
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Why `sudo` ? `sudo` is always run with superuser privileges (as root). Thus sudo has the ability to do some privileged tasks like calling system functions only allowed for root. Since you are getting a `permission denied` error, running the same command using `sudo` will not ask for permission since you are root

Comment: This would answer the question, but a little bit of context as to why this should be done would help OP and future SOers tremendously

Comment: I'm still having an issue with pip uninstall matplotlib.

Comment: I don't think advertising ``sudo`` for something like this is a good idea. The right way to do it is checking and if necessary altering the file/folder permissions for the installation.